# A href not working when onclick works

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onclick, tags

Subject is a problem. Well I have, for example, this html

```
<a href="/en/pages/socials.aspx">Learn more</a>
```

It doesn't work. Okay, perhaps there are some invisible elements that don't allow to click on it. Here I add onclick property:

```
<a href="/ru/pages/socials.aspx" onclick="javascript:alert('Hi');">Learn more</a>
```

But now I see that "Hi" message appears (so `<a>` tag is clickable), but it doesn't change current page.

Well, ok. Now i'm changing javascript to:

```
<a onclick="window.location.href='/ru/pages/socials.aspx';return false;"  href="/ru/pages/socials.aspx">Learn more</a>
```

and now it works as espected, but I'm looking for non-JS pure HTML solution.

Please, advice. Why `<a>` could be non-clickable for href, but with workable JS onclick event?

Comment: Check the elements with Developer tools.

Comment: Amazing. How could it be? Your syntax is perfect. Agree with @GuyT.

Comment: Maybe you are referencing the same page. I mean, is your href referencing the same page you are in?

Comment: @dreyescat no, I'm not referencing the same page.

Comment: @GuyT what *exactly* should I check? Because I have no idea, otherwise I don't post this message on SO.

Comment: Does this work:
`<a href="/ru/pages/socials.aspx" onclick="javascript:$('a').unbind('click');">Learn more</a>`

Comment: @dreyescat great idea. Your code doesn't work too. And now we see that it's not an onclick handler in another JS file... So strange...

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky If there is an other layer visible when you are hovering the link(with the inspector).

Comment: And if we unbind all the event handlers for this specific link?
`<a href="/ru/pages/socials.aspx"  onclick="javascript:$(this).unbind();">Learn more</a>`

Comment: @dreyescat no reaction

Comment: Let's see what is the content of the href when you click... `<a href="/ru/pages/socials.aspx" onclick="javascript:alert(this.href);">Learn more</a>`. Maybe other script is just voiding/removing it...

Comment: @dreyescat showing valid url...

Comment: I have run out of ideas ;). Try to disable javascript in the browser... Otherwise, I don't see any other solution than trying to comment out all your js files as @pstrohmeyer suggests.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky And.. Are there other layers on top of the link?

Comment: @GuyT there is no other layers. Well, I finally got tired of this HTML hell and just used JS href. It's not what do I want, but it still work at least. Thanks for help, people (no sarcasm).

Answer (score 2):

Did you add click event listeners via e.g. JQuery? Maybe you're disabling the default behaviour by something like this:

```
$(..).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

I would exclude 'wrong' markup ( like an overlapping div or something ) because you can use the link when you add an inline onclick.

Comment: I don't. But i have multiple JS file connected (several dozens), and it may exist somewhere

Comment: see if it works if you remove/comment out all js file references. If so, try commenting out every file step by step to see which one causes the problem.